# Laravel4 -- Using wildcard subdomains, but keep the routing style of Route::controller('user', 'UserController');

Tags: laravel, routes, subdomain, wildcard

I have to convert a site to make use of wildcard subdomains (right now it isn't using them).

I like using the routing style of `Route::controller('user', 'UserController');`

The subdomain example in the docs is:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('user/{id}', function($account, $id)
    {
        //
    });
});
```

But this uses the format of `Route::get('user/{id}'...`. The user controller does so much more, and the first method handles everything so I prefer it.

I'd like to get the subdomain information into the user controller (and all other controllers, really), in a "Laravel way" if at all possible. Is there a standard way of doing that?

Comment: Add `$account` as the first parameter in your methods, then you can  get the subdomain name.

Comment: @Razor - Perfect! Do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: If there's no subdomain present, it gives a 404... I'm trying to find a way around that. Right now I'm using a Before filter that checks for at least two periods in the host, and if there isn't it redirects it to "www". But it would be really cool to use no "www" or subdomain as default.

Comment: I'm pretty confused, what do you want exactly if there's no subdomain?

Comment: @Razor - A default homepage / not a 404 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function()
{
    Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
}
Route::get('/',array('as'=>'homePage' , function()
{
    return "my home page";
}));
```

Then in `UserController`, add `$account` as the first parameter in your methods

```php
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex($account)
    {
        return $account;
    }
}
```